# How does an IV regression/2SLS affect coefficient (increase/decrease) with initial simultaneity?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, econometrics, instrumental-variables, 2sls

So let's say I want to look at how `X` affects `Y`, but there is some simultaneity going on: `X` is affecting `Y`; `Y` is affecting `X`.

BUT ALAS, I find a great instrument (relevant to x, does not affect y except through x) -- `Z`.

Now, I regress x on Z, get a variable called `xhat`, and then regress that on `Y`.

**Under what conditions would the `xhat` coefficient be larger or smaller than the `x` coefficient?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that

$$y=\alpha_1 \cdot x + u_1 \\ x=\alpha_2 \cdot y+u_2, $$
where the $u$s are uncorrelated. You can show that

$$Cov(x,u_1)=\left(\frac{\alpha_2}{1-\alpha_1\alpha_2} \right) \cdot Var(u_1)$$

This means the OLS bias in the first equation will have the same sign as the first factor in the parentheses, since the variance is always positive. So if $\alpha_2>0$, and $\alpha_2 \alpha_1<1$, the OLS will have positive bias asymptotically, compared to IV.

The more general case is unfortunately not as simple.

Comment: @thewhitetie Did this help?